# Concatenate 4 Html pages without InnerHtml

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Here is the deal,

I work on the Googl apps script IDE and 
have four HTML files that I would like to merge together into a HtmlOutput object.

```
Template.html
Content.html
Script.html
Style.html
```

Here is the what I would like to get:

Have the Script.html and Style.html into the  part of my Template.html
   and put the Content.html in my body part.

The problem is I cannot find a way to convert a  HtmlOutput object  output to a Document Object this way I could use the InnerHtml proprerty.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of templates with HtmlSerivce.
Take a look at the best practices for Htmlservice templates. It shows how to do this.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices#separate_html_css_and_javascript

The basic idea is that you have your file with your template tags that is build from other html files in your project.

page.html

```
<?!= include('Stylesheet'); ?>

<h1>Welcome</h1>
<p><?!= include('Content'); ?></p>

<?!= include('JavaScript'); ?>
```

code.gs

```
function doGet(request) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Page')
      .evaluate();
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
      .getContent();
}
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your help. I already saw this technic in the doc but How can I merge for example the content.html file between the <h1> tag and the <p> tag of your example?

Comment: Look at the edit. It is as simple as using the include() method from code.gs

Comment: I got it now. I didn't noticed the include in the html was related to the one in the gs. Thanks again